# I am using window.location.replace take time to render the reponse?

Tags: javascript, performance

The actual scenario is like I have 6k table rows which coming after the new action call. Below is call

```
var url = parent.getActionURL('fullExpand') + '?object=' + getTableBeanName();
    if (typeof levels !== 'undefined') {
        url += '&expandTo=' + levels;
    }
    window.location.replace(url);
```

The reponse is coming from server but it is not rendering in ui if we touch any dom  element then reponse is rendering.if we change window.location.replace to window.location.href = url. Then problem get resolved for first time the behaviour is not consistent

Comment: What do you want to archive and what do you mean with "behavior is not consistent"? It is quite hard helping you with such limited information.

Comment: Have you taken a look at my answer? Consider giving some feedback, greetings!

Answer (score 0):

The question is not totally clear, but they both navigate to the URL. `replace()` replaces the current document and it doesn't add a record to `history`, the behavior should be consistent in both cases.

With `replace()`, when the user clicks the back button they are returned to the page before the page that they were redirected from, this might cause your confusion. ([read here](https://www.endyourif.com/difference-between-location-href-and-location-replace/))

You should use what is best for your use case.